# Meaning and examples of Grothendieck condition AB4*

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

What are some examples of AB4* categories? In particular, for a thesis I am writing I need to know if cochain-complexes form an AB4* category

Comment: You [posted the first half of this question yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462678/definition-of-product-coproduct-of-exact-sequences) - reposting so soon is not acceptable behavior here at MSE. I'd recommend editing this question down to the final bit - "What are some examples of AB4* catergories" and "do cochain-complexes form an AB4* category?"

Comment: Cochain complexes of … what? Modules? Sheaves of abelian groups? Please be precise!

Comment: @ZhenLin are there examples of abelian categories $A$ where with all products where the axiom is not satisified for $\mathrm{Ch}(A)$? Or are you worried strictly about completeness?

Comment: @ZhenLin Modules

Comment: @StefanDawydiak Completeness does not imply AB4*. Sheaves, for example.